# Check only checkboxes with a specific value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check only checkboxes that have a specific value.
I know how to get the value and I know how to check all checkboxes but I cannot figure out how to check only the ones with, lets say value of '200'

My example code:

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="200" /></td>
    <td class="code">200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    <td class="code">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    <td class="code">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="200" /></td>
    <td class="code">200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="300" /></td>
    <td class="code">300</td>
</tr>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_200" label="check 200"  />check 200
```

So now I need jQuery code to complete my code.
I appreciate any help.

BTW. Is there a way to check '200' and '300' in one go?

UPDATED!

Comment: Where is _your_ code?

Comment: That is a good point, I don't have chk_box value. I was editing this code so long that I've missed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your checkboxes do not have `value` attributes, if you want to check the checkboxes according to the text content of the TD elements, you can use `filter` method.

```
$('td.code').filter(function(){
   var txt = this.textContent || this.innerText;
   return txt === '200' || txt === '300';  
}).prev().find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

**Update**:

```
$('tr input[type=checkbox][value=200]').prop('checked', true);
```

Alternative:

```
$('tr input[type=checkbox]').filter(function(){
   return this.value === '200' || this.value === '300';
}).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Is there a way to have check, uncheck option?

Comment: @Chriser Yes, use `false` instead of `true` in `prop` method.

Answer (score 4):

Your checkboxes has not value. There is only text next ty its.
Try to change code and set value for inputs.

```
<input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="200" /> 200
<br />
<input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="0" />0
<br />
<input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="0" />0
<br />
<input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="200" /> 200
<br />
<input class="chk_box" type="checkbox" value="300" /> 300
```

The you can use this selector:

```
input[type=checkbox][value="200"]
```

For jquery use it inside $("").

Example:
http://jsbin.com/oyetit/1/edit

Comment: Thank you for that, I've just messed up the initial code, now updated.

Comment: to make 200 & 300 selected at once use this:
    $('input[type=checkbox][value="200"],input[type=checkbox][value="300"]').prop("checked",true);

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I end up with this solution, slightly modified and with thanks to @undefined:

```
var chk = $(this).attr('checked')?true:false;
$('tr input[type=checkbox][value=200]').attr('checked',chk);
```

This allows me to check / uncheck checkboxes with values I am interested in.

And the same for multiple values:

```
var chk = $(this).attr('checked')?true:false;
$('tr input[type=checkbox]').filter(function(){
    return this.value === '200' || this.value === '300';
}).attr('checked',chk);
```